# JQuery reusable functions

Tags: jquery, function, row, reusability

Completely new to JQuery so I am learning everyday.

One thing I noticed is how easy it is, you can just write

```
$('div#test).remove();
```

But I am looking for an example on how to reuse some code, eg.:

```
function RemoveTableRow(row, id) 
{
   $(row).remove();
   // id should be used for ajax call
}
```

And then add a 'onclick' on my anchor-tag

```
onclick="RemoveTableRow('user-row-1', 32);"
```

But somehow it is not working, even if I add it on document.ready function. Can someone cut it out for me, the best practice way for doing this?

Thanks in advance. This forum is killer!

**Update**

I updated the code from the help I got here. This is my current code, and I would like to know if its the best way of doing this.

```
function RemoveTableRow(row, id) {
            $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "Default.aspx/DeleteEmployee",
             data: "{'ID':'" + id + "'}",
             beforeSend: function() {
                  $("#" + row).animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
             },
             success: function() {
              $("#" + row).slideUp(300,function() {
                    $("#" + row).remove();
              });
             }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors?

Comment: The code in your edit looks fine and looks like the best way to do it. I wouldn't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is user-row-1 the ID of the table row? If yes, than you are missing # in your selector

```
function RemoveTableRow(row, id) {
   $('#'+row).remove();
   // id should be used for ajax call
}
```

or without changing the function, call it with the complete selector

```
onclick="RemoveTableRow('#user-row-1', 32);"
```

Comment: Of course! This works! Is this the best way of doing this? Or do you recommend something else?

Comment: It's not a bad way, but you could use more of the jQuery abilities. If you have a delete button in every row (just read your comment to kgiannakakis's answer) for example (<tr><td><button class="deleteButtons"/></td></tr>), you could bind click event-listeners to those delete buttons, and find parent TR element of that button.
$('.deleteButtons').click(function(e){$(this).parent().parent().remove()})
or
$('.deleteButtons').click(function(e){$(this).parents('tr').eq(0).remove()})
This should work

Comment: That is great. But I need to pass some parameters with the click?

Comment: In this case, I have no clear idea, but if you could explain, how are you using these parameters, what do the numbers mean, than maybe I'll be able to give an alternative solution. Post, please, some more code (the rest of the RemoveTableRow function)

Comment: sorry, didn't find any better solution, so my first answer will be the final

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to bind the onclick to? Assuming it is a DOM element with id myid, then this will do:

```
("#myid").click(function () {RemoveTableRow('user-row-1', 32);} );
```

Comment: I have some table rows with a delete button on the end of each, where the output is from dynamic code, so I need someway of avoiding the hard-coded ID to click on.